# SP 2013: Display Field Name & Value in two places on Edit Form

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery, form, edit-form

I have a very long form and I need to leave a field [Field1] at the bottom of the Edit Form but display the name and value towards the top of the edit form.

Can Jquery get the field name and value and display it above? The display would not be editable, only the [Field1] at the bottom

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

To customize long form, jQuery tabs would be a good choice and this can be implemented in SharePoint form CSR.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1039724/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p-2

Anyway, you could use jQuery with JSOM/rest api to customize list forms DOM elements.

[jQuery prepend to append DOM elements to specific node](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)